# How to format data for a django template?

Tags: python, django

This is a sample of my data:

```
Network Policy
    Level 1: John Smith
    Start date: 27 April
    Start time: 8am
    end Date: 05 May
    end time: 8am
    Level 2: Bob Smith
    Start date: 27 April
    Start time: 8am
    end Date: 05 May
    end time: 8am
Server Policy
    Level 1: Jane Doe
    Start date: 23 April
    Start time: 8am
    end Date: 02 May
    end time: 8am
    Level 2: Greg Brad
    Start date: 23 April
    Start time: 8am
    end Date: 02 May
    end time: 8am
```

I need to arrange this data in such a format that I can use it as a template in django. I thought I needed nested dictionaries at first, but that doesn't work, as I need multiple values under the same Key.

I'm new to Python, so please correct the above if I'm wrong.

EDIT:

this is as far as ive got,

i have Dict > list , not sure how to get a dict into the list though that matches?

```
### Get all the Polices ###
dictContext = {}
for objPolicy in objPolicyData['escalation_policies']:
    strPolicyName = objPolicy['name']   
    if strPolicyName.lower().find('test') == -1:
        lstLevel = []
        dictContext[strPolicyName] = lstLevel
        for objOnCall in objPolicy['on_call']:
            dictUser = {}
            lstLevel.append(objOnCall['level'])
            dictUser['strStartDate'] =  getDate(objOnCall['start'])
            dictUser['strStartTime'] = getTime(objOnCall['start'])
            dictUser['strEndDate'] =  getDate(objOnCall['end'])
            dictUser['strEndTime'] = getTime(objOnCall['end'])
            objUser = objOnCall['user']
            dictUser['strUsername'] =  objUser['name']
            dictUser['strUserMobile'] = getUserMobile(objUser['id'])
            #lstLevel.append(dictUser)
```

result is

```
{
    u'DBA Escalation Policy': [1],
    u'Server Escalation Policy': [1],
    u'Network Team Escalation Policy': [1, 2],
    }
```

so my next step is to have the user details under each level

it needs to go

```
Policy1 > Level 1 > level 1 user details | Level 2 > Level 2 user details
Policy2 > Level 1 > level 1 user details 
Policy3 > Level 1 > level 1 user details | Level 2 > Level 2 user details | Level 3 > Level 3 user details
```

this is my goal

Thanks

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: It looks like you have two separate things under each policy (eg. it looks like one "Start date" applies to "John Smith", one applies to "Bob Smith" etc.). Maybe you need dict -> list -> dict. At this point, I don't see what your question has to do with django

Comment: @SpoonMeiser removed django, i put django as thats what i was sending the data to. can you show me a sample of what i need?

Comment: @AlexW If you need multiple values under the same key, why not just assign a list to that key, and append your values to that list? Then in your Django template you can just iterate through the elements of the value list.

Comment: Your question says you want "use it as a template in django", so that's still part of the topic.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser ive updated my code and latest attempt if you could help me?

Comment: Why can't you pass objPolicyData directly to your templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using primitive types, your data probably translates to something like this:

```
policy = {
    "Network": [
        {
            "Name": "John Smith",
            "Start_date": "27 April",
            "Start_time": "8am",
            "end_Date": "05 May",
            "end_time": "8am"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Bob Smith",
            "Start_date": "27 April",
            "Start_time": "8am",
            "end_Date": "05 May",
            "end_time": "8am"
        },
    ]
    "Server": [
        # ...
    ]
}
```

In a django template then, you could refer to, for example:

```
{% policy.Network.0.name %}
```

(levels are 0-indexed, so use `level - 1`)

And you can also iterate over the levels in each policy.

To make this data structure from the data structure you already have (judging by your code example) you'd do something like:

```
policy = {}

# is there a better way here? Are we iterating a dict or a list?
for policy_data in objPolicyData['escalation_policies']:
    policy_name = policy_data["name"]

    # this is a better approach that the find method you employed
    if "test" in policy_name:
        continue

    def sort_key(user_data):
        return user_data["level"]

    # just using a list comprehension to map the objects from the current
    # form to your desired form, making sure we iterate over them in
    # level order
    policy[policy_name] = [
        {
            "name": user_data["name"]
            "start_date": getDate(user_data['start'])
            "start_time": getTime(user_data['start'])
            "end_date": getDate(user_data['end'])
            "end_time": getTime(user_data['end'])
        }
        for user_data in sorted(policy_data["on_call"], key=sort_key)
    ]
```

I'd probably consider having objects that represent your data, and providing an interface that works with django templates' limitations, rather than using primitives, because otherwise you end up with both your templates and your view code being tightly coupled to the structure of the data.

Comment: How do i structure my code to create what you have put above? also how do i create objects instead if that approach is better? Thanks

Comment: @AlexW updated with a code example. I have no idea what you want to do with this data in your templates, so I can't design objects for you.